When is the closable composition of operators affiliated to a von Neumann algebra also an affiliated operator?
Let $S$ and $T$ be closed (unbounded) operators affiliated to a von Neumann algebra $M$.
Can we say anything about when the closure of their composition $T \circ S$ is also affiliated to $M$ (assuming that it is densly defined and closable)?
Exercise 9.26 in Stratila and Zsido's 'Lectures on von Neumann algebras' says that if $M$ is a FINITE von Neumann algebra, its closed affiliated operators form a *-algebra. From that I guess that it works only for the finite case. Can anything be said about a generic $M$?

Probably not. When $M$ is a factor, say, if it is not finite then it admits a tensor component of $B(l^2)$, so you basically get all densely defined closed operators on $l^2$ incorporated into the set of all closed affiliated operators of $M$. Of courses there are densely defined closed operators on $l^2$ whose composition is no longer densely defined.

Thanks! Of course, makes sense. I edited the question to better describe what is interesting to me  ('assuming that the composition is densly defined or even closable')

In that case the composition is always affiliated to $M$, practically by definition.

Thanks a lot! Indeed, that is easy to show
